# Mouse events not triggering for child in flipped SwiftUI List

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm attempting to build a standard chat UI in SwiftUI, with a flipped `List` for its performance. The `List` needs to be flipped in order for elements to "stick" to the bottom of the screen when new ones are added, as well as preserving scroll position when messages are lazily backfilled.

However, I'm encountering an issue where mouse events are not triggered on any child of a flipped `List`, whether tap or hover events.

Here's a reproducible sample:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                Text("abcd \(i)")
                    .onHover { hov in print("hover \(i): \(hov)") }
                    .onTapGesture { coord in print("tap \(i): \(coord)") }
            }
            .rotationEffect(.radians(.pi))
            .scaleEffect(x: -1.0, y: 1.0, anchor: .center)
        }
        .rotationEffect(.radians(.pi))
        .scaleEffect(x: -1.0, y: 1.0, anchor: .center)
    }
}
```

Simply replacing the `List` with a `LazyVStack` fixes the issue, but that's not desired as it leads to subpar performance (as the complexity of children grows).

Take a look at the following [video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/64193267/221361605-01ff6e51-8dbf-41f0-a14d-d2cf8b183d6b.mp4) for a demonstration of the bug and behaviour comparison to `LazyVStack`.

It would be great if there is a solution to this, because it's currently a huge development block. Answers would be greatly appreciated! =D

Comment: As of MacOS 11, SwiftUI has ScrollViewReader which can be used to position the scrolling for Chat-like behavior without flipping. Must you support Catalina(10.15)?

Comment: With scrollViewReader, keeping the chat history stuck to the bottom without jank is especially difficult (as a scroll has to be initiated with every mutation of the messages), and does not preserve scroll positions when messages are lazily loaded.

Comment: I posted an example that seems to work, just in case it's helpful. Granted though I don't know your project.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a small mac app that has chat-like scrolling and works with the mouse hovering and tapping. The code uses a ScrollViewReader, ScrollView and LazyVStack. The LazyVStack can be replaced with a VStack and some minor code changes.

[image]

Example chat app:

```
struct ChatView: View {
    @State var items: [Item] = []
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var targetItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                ChatStyleScrollView() {
                    ForEach(items) { i in
                        ItemView(item: i)
                            .onHover { hov in print("hover \(i): \(hov)") }
                            .onTapGesture { coord in print("tap \(i): \(coord)") }
                            .id(i.id)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: targetItem) { item in
                    if let item = item {
                        withAnimation(.default) {
                            scrollView.scrollTo(item.id)
                        }
                    }
                }
                TextEntryView(items: $items, text: $text, targetItem: $targetItem)
            }
        }
    }
}

    //MARK: - Item Model with unique identifier
struct Item: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var text: String
}

    //MARK: - ScrollView that pushes text to the bottom of the display
struct ChatStyleScrollView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer()
                    content
                }
                .frame(minHeight: geo.size.height * 2 )
            }
        }
    }
}

//  //MARK: - A single item and its layout
struct ItemView: View {
    var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.text)
            .lineSpacing(0)
            .padding(.leading)
    }
}


    //MARK: - User Input Area - TextField and Send button
struct TextEntryView: View {
    @Binding var items: [Item]
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var targetItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Item", text: $text)
                .frame(height: 44)
            Button(action: send) { Text("Send") }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    func send() {
        guard !text.isEmpty else { return }
        let item = Item(id: UUID(), text: text)
        items.append(item)
        text = ""
        targetItem = item
    }
}
```